# how set splitpane divider width in javafx 2

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have SplitPane in my application. This is SplitPane have divider with default width. 
How can i set the width of SplitPane Divider

```
@FXML
private SplitPane splitPane;
// splitPane here get Divider and set New Width
```

Comment: Can you clarify: did you literally mean the width of the divider (i.e. the size of the piece the user can move around), or did you mean the width of the panes (i.e. the position of the divider in the `SplitPane`)?

Comment: @James_D  the size of the piece the user can move around

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use css to change the width of the divider:

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {  
    -fx-padding: 0 0.75em 0 0.75em;  
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in the fxml file directly?

Answer (score -2):

For JavaFX8: If you create your view from .fxml file, you can set divider's position using the attribute `dividerPosition` of the node `SplitPane`:

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3">

</SplitPane>
```